# jquery ui slider downloading

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

How can I download custom jquery ui package with slider widgets included? I tried to download from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) but although I checked it I cannot find it in the downloaded package. I cannot even find any word 'slider' in the result js.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to that page and checking "Slider" should automatically check "Core", "Widget", and "Mouse". The resulting jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.zip/js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js will have the Slider widget and you can double check that jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.zip/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js exists. I just double-checked this process and it worked as expected with Chrome/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you download from the page you are at (and don't uncheck any of the boxes), you will get the slider component of jQuery UI. Have you actually tried using the library instead of searching within the JavaScript for it? If you need more help on how to use the slider, [head to the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

Comment: Hi! I unchecked the widgets and effects I don't need. Of couse, I left 'slider' as checked. After downloading and adding refference to my page I still have 'slider is not a function' error. I searched by word 'slider' in the downloaded js file, but there is no such word here. It's very strange.